# The function name conflicts with the function in the Kernel module. Is there a way to call its own function first?

Tags: erlang, elixir

For example, `div/2` is an existing function in the `Kernel` module. I want to call my own `div/2` function instead of the `Kernel.div/2` function.

Comment: You can do that but I'd think long and hard about naming my functions the same as kernel functions.  You're potentially adding a lot of maintenance headaches for those who maintain your code later (maybe even you in six months).  Especially when it's easy to name a function udiv (for user-defined division) or something that makes it clear that it's not the kernel function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can un-import a function in `Kernel` by explicitly importing `Kernel` and excluding the functions you don't want with the `except` option:

```
defmodule A do
  import Kernel, except: [div: 2]

  def div(a, b), do: a * b

  def do_div, do: div(3, 4)
end

IO.inspect A.do_div()
```

Output:

```
12
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also call 
`<module-name>.div/2` from inside your `<module-name>`

Answer (score 0):

Besides un-import the function you also can explicitly refer to your own module when calling the function

```elixir
defmodule MyModule do
    def div(a, b) do
        a * b
    end 

    def do_div do
        __MODULE__.div(3, 4)
    end
end
```